# remove DISPLAY name of email in mysql

Tags: mysql, regex, replace

I have a table called msgs. It has a column called from_addr.

its OUTPUT is like this.

```
select from_addr from msgs;
```

from_addr

```
root@example.com (root)
sender2@yahoo.com (sender2)
u1@example.com
```

My expected OUTPUT is

```
root@example.com
sender2@yahoo.com
u1@example.com
```

I want to remove DISPLAY name (displayname) of the email address.

I don't want to update the table permanantly.

I used below command

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE((select from_addr from msgs),' \(.*\)','');
```

I get below error.

```
ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

How can I achieve it.

Hope to hear from you.

Comment: there is no ouput.

Comment: This looks like SQL, please [edit] to specify the dialect and add pertinent tags.

Comment: An added complication is that there are multiple email address formats in common use.  The regular RFC format is `Real Name <address@example.com>` but Microsoft insists on quoted `"Name, Real" <address@example.com>`. The examples in your question use an older legacy format where the real name is technically a free-form comment `address@example.com (anything you like here)`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work.

```
select from_addr, regexp_replace(regexp_replace(from_addr, '(\n|^) \(.*\)(\n|$)', '\n'), ' \(.*\)' , '' ) from_addr_alias from msgs;
```

OUTPUT

```
 from_addr                 | from_addr_alias
root@example.com.lk       | root@example.com.lk
root@example.com (root)   | root@example.com  
user@lk.example.com       | user@lk.example.com 
root@example.com (root)   | root@example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

In php way.

```
<!-- <td><?php echo $row["from_addr"]; ?></td> --> // this displays as it is. 
<td><?php echo preg_replace('/\s\(.*\)/', '', $row["from_addr"]); ?></td> // This removes (DisplayName) from from_addr.
```